# How to generate combination similar to 'n Choose r' from std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple>>>?

Tags: c++

I wanted to get something along the lines of 'x choose 3'. So for example

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] choose 3
-> [1,2,3]
-> [1,2,4]
-> [1,3,4]
-> [2,3,4]
```

Now there are several ways of doing that but I want to do something similar on a variable I defined like this

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>> v;
```

but I want to choose this whole type

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>>
```

so one can think of it as

```
std::vector<a> choose 3
```

Looking around I found something that can help here. Specifically the `for_each_reversiable_permutation`

I think the usage is

```
for_each_reversible_permutation(v.begin(), v.begin() + r, v.end(), f(v.size()));
```

which in my case should be

```
for_each_reversible_permutation(v.begin(), v.begin() + 5, v.end(), v.size());
```

Although I'm not sure because that doesn't work.

Also I don't know if there's a faster more specific way of generating combination for `std::vector`

Comment: Where did you find that `for_each_reversiable_permutation`? Provide a link please.

Comment: My question to you is, are you wanting permutations? Or subsets of a vector?

Comment: I don't follow that discussion about the types involved. 1) "do something similar" -- so not "n choose r"? What do you want to do? 2) "I want to choose this whole type" -- "choose" is probably not the right word for what you mean, and what makes a type "whole"? 3) "think of it as" -- think of what as? What is the supposed to be the antecedent of "it"? Sorry if that seems nit-picky, but your question does seem to hinge on that part, and I don't understand what it's trying to say. Maybe more code would help?